# According to POSIX, when will my writes be visible to other processes?

Tags: concurrency, file-io, posix, system-calls, file-descriptor

If I open a file with `O_CREAT | O_WRONLY` and `write` to it. Does POSIX say 1) other apps can see the file in the folder (without fsync) and 2) be able to see what I wrote?

Same questions after I do `close` without an `fsync`.

Now finally will it once my program ends? I understand fsync will confirm my write is on disk but I don't need my file to be on disk, I need it to be visible to other processes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, other processes see your writes immediately.  You do not need to close or fsync.

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html

> Writes can be serialized with respect to other reads and writes. If a read() of file data can be proven (by any means) to occur after a write() of the data, it must reflect that write(), even if the calls are made by different processes. A similar requirement applies to multiple write operations to the same file position. This is needed to guarantee the propagation of data from write() calls to subsequent read() calls.

This means, for instance, that if the OS caches your write instead of actually writing it to disk, it needs to ensure that any other reads of that file are fulfilled from that same cache.

Comment: Thanks. I write why the man pages on my system doesn't say anything like that :/

Comment: What system is that?  Linux's man page for `write(2)` says it pretty clearly, for instance.  In the Description section: "POSIX  requires  that a read(2) that can be proved to occur after a write() has returned will return the new data."

Comment: I just found out it says it in `man 3 write` but not `man 2 write`